maven-release Plugin in GitLab CLI with token
The project I'm working on utilizes the maven-release plugin to manage versions and publish artifacts to the package registry. To use it in the context of a GitLab CI pipeline, I went with the SSH key workaround so far, which makes this work:
release-job:
  image: maven:3.9.6-eclipse-temurin-17-focal
  stage: release
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $VERSION'
  script:
    - git config --global user.email "bla@bla.org" # just putting some stuff in here
    - git config --global user.name "GitLab"
    - mvn -B -DscmCommentPrefix="[skip ci]" release:prepare release:perform -DreleaseVersion=$VERSION --settings settings.xml

Because SSH keys are tied to a specific user's GitLab account and require more setup than an Access Token, I want to make the switch to those now. For that, I have to use an https-remote like this: https://oauth2:$TOKEN@$REPO_URL (variable names should be pretty self explanatory here). To my bewilderment, I haven't managed to make Maven use that git remote, though.
First, I tried to set the git remote in a step in the script like this: git remote set-url --push https://oauth2:$TOKEN@$REPO_URL. In the pipeline's logs, I can see though that Maven ignores the git remote and tries to push to the ssh remote that's set up in the pom.xml: [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/builds/dev/pipeline-test' && 'git' 'push' 'git@****/pipeline-test.git' 'refs/heads/main:refs/heads/main' (acutal repository URL redacted, the git@*** part is where it should say https://... but doesn't).
Next, I tried to pass in the remote via an argument: mvn -B -DconnectionUrl=scm:git:$REMOTE ...
Maven ignores that as well. I've went through the better part of the entire project's documentation and tried every option I could find there how to pass in that variable, but the result is always the same.
Has anybody ever done that and can tell me how I can force the Maven Release plugin to push to a different git remote?

To make maven-release-plugin use the gitlab project access token, you can follow the below steps:

Create a Gitlab Access Token with api permission
Create a Gitlab Variable with the value of Access Token, let's call it MavenReleaseToken
in your pom.xml modify the scm :



<scm>     <connection>scm:git:https://root:$MavenReleaseToken@gitlab.company.de/gitlab/demo.git</connection>
        <url>https://gitlab.company.de/gitlab/demo.git</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag> </scm>




in your mvn command use -Dusername=root -Dpassword=$MavenReleaseToken

For further information see this: https://blog.ordix.de/maven-release-mit-der-gitlab-ci
